# Difference between 0,30 and */30?

Tags: cron, cpanel

cPanel shows the syntax for running a cron every 5, 10, or 15 minutes as

```
*/15
```

But it shows the syntax for running a cron every 30 minutes as

```
0,30
```

Why the syntax difference? Why not have every 30 minutes be like the others? I.e:

```
*/30
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have Vixie Cron, `0,30` in the minutes field means the same thing as `*/30`, i.e., run at 0 and 30 minutes after the hour.

I don't know what "cPanel" is, or why it chooses to use different syntax for that case. Perhaps it uses the `*/15` syntax because it's more convenient than `0,15,30,45`, and the `0,30` syntax because it's more portable (to Cron implementations other than Vixie).